# How to unit test a binary format reader class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, binaryfiles

I am working on a class which reads a binary file and stores the value present in that binary file.

> The question is how to unit test this class, What I have done right
>   now is, I deployed a sample file and wrote a unit test for that
>   particular file only.

Example:- I know that first value in binary file will be a integer and its value will be 60. So I write unit test for that. I have written tests for the whole file. Are those unit-tests enough? Or should I write some more.

Sample Unit-test. I have written tests for all values.

```
[TestMethod]
public void First_Integer_Read_Value_Is_60
{
    // Arrange
    var expected = 60;
    var reader = new MyCustomBinaryReader(filepath);

    // Act
    var actual = reader.FirstValue;

    //
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual)
}

reader.FirstValue
{
    get { return BinaryReader.ReadInt32(); }
}
```

So I am getting 100% code coverage. But is that testing enough? How do we unit-test these kind of classes.

Comment: Are you just *reading* the file, or does your code also *write* it?

Comment: Right now there is only reading stuff, but might be I add writing stuff as well. It depends on requirements, currently there is no plan for writing code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are purely concern about the Test coverage of the MyCustomBinaryReader, since you are getting 100% code coverage, that means your test has sufficiently covered the code that does "read" behaviour. Since you are getting the correct values, you are also reading the file correctly.

It is harder to know your exact requirements. But if it is important for you to read every single value in that file, then assuming all your tests covers every single value then you have the data coverage 100%. This has nothing to do with the code coverage.

What you can improve?
Instead of creating many tests, you can look at using DataDriven Tests
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527.aspx
This approach allows you to easily change the external files/values without having to recompile the code. Also less code/less Tests.

You also said currently it is only reading stuff, but might writing stuff in future. As its current state your Test has covered what is required (i,e reading). The writing requirement does not available at this stage so you don't need concern about it.

Just a side note/not related:- Your MyCustomBinaryReader must be reading a file from a disk. Therefore this is not a Unit Test and this is an data driven integration type test.